# Elastic Search Stopped Working without any logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, spree

I'm using Elastic Search with my Spree Ecommerce application but every random number of days elastic search stops working and when i check logs under /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log i don't find anything useful just Stopping...

any idea why this happens? my server is 8 GB Ram, with 20GB Storge & elasticsearch v6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Absence of a Swap file was the cause of the issue.